# Error al generar reporte odoo 12

Tags: xml, odoo

Estoy creando un report en point_of_sale aqui esta mi codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <report 
            id="point_of_sale_reports"
            model="pos.session"
            string="Reporte Sesion"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="hn_pos_sar.hn_point_of_sale_report"
            file="hn_pos_sar.hn_point_of_sale_report"
        />

    </data>
</odoo>
```

y mi reporte hn_point_if_sale_report , tiene lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
   <data>
     <template id="hn_point_of_sale_report">
        <div class="page">
            <h6>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h6>
        </div>
     </template>  
   </data>
</odoo>
```

El boton de imprimir se crea correctamente , el problema es al querer cargar el reporte me tirar error interno de servidor , y en la consola no tira nada que me ayude.

El error en consola es este: 
[image: y en la pestaña donde se deberia de abrir el reporte solamente sale error interno de servidor]

Ayudenme a saber donde me estoy equivocando. 
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué dice tu log? ¿qué error tienes ahí?

Comment: Mi log? , el error en consola ahi esta actualize el post.

Comment: Dice el índice está fuera del rango. Si compartes algo más del código

Comment: ahi esta todo mi codigo

Answer (score 0):

Hacian falta estas lineas en la estructura:

```
<t t-call="web.html_container">
     <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
         <div>
            <h6>holaa</h6>
         </div>  
     </t>
</t>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto en hn_point_if_sale_report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
   <data>
     <template id="hn_point_of_sale_report">
     <t t-call="web.html_container">
     <t t-call="web.internal_layout">
        <div class="page">
            <h6>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h6>
        </div>
     </t>    
     </t>
     </template>  
   </data>
</odoo>
```

Ref: [Pregunta relacionada](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/create-a-custom-report-in-odoo12-error-index-out-of-range-how-to-solve-it-147195)